# Google Analytics import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, import, google-analytics

I am trying to track `pageviews` with `Google Analytics` but I keep getting an error on the import.  I have listed in the code below where the errors are.

I also have put the jar file in the java build path and added the two lines in the `Android Manifest`.

My question is how to get the below code to compile correctly.

```
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;  //Error:  "The import com.google.android.apps cannot be resolved"

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;  //Error:  "The import com.google.android.apps cannot be resolved to a type"

    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenumain);

        tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance();
        tracker.startSession("UA-38788135-1", this);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                tracker.trackPageView("/Categories");  //Error:  "The import com.google.android.apps cannot be resolved to a type"
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Categories.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                tracker.trackPageView("/Highscores");  //Error:  "The import com.google.android.apps cannot be resolved to a type"
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Highscores.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                tracker.trackPageView("/About");  //Error:  "The import com.google.android.apps cannot be resolved to a type"
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                tracker.trackPageView("/ComingSoon");  //Error:  "The import com.google.android.apps cannot be resolved to a type"
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, ComingSoon.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @Eric - I found that topic earlier and the solution did not work.

Comment: You should always share what you've tried prior to asking the question; knowing that kind of thing would help us.

Comment: Thank you, good to know for the future.

Comment: The analytics jar has to be in the "libs" folder. Don't put the jar in libs/GoogleAnalyticsAndroid, put it in /libs. Look at the actual files on the file system or the "navigator" view in Eclipse. The ADT and GA require that path (don't mess with the Eclipse settings yourself, just put it in libs and clean, that should work).https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/

Comment: Also, if you get an error compiling, share that. What error are you getting?

Comment: Still get the same exact errors compiling.  I updated my directory screenshot to show the fixes you suggested.  If anything the changes made it look neater.

As for the link you gave, that talks something about ````EasyTracker````.  I don't have anything in my code about an ````EasyTracker````.  Should I?

Comment: You don't have to use EasyTracker, but you can. If you don't want to, that's fine too, the other class you might use is called "Tracker" though, not "GoogleAnalyticsTracker." There is no class named "GoogleAnalyticsTracker," hence the error. See the "getting started" doc I linked earlier, that should help.

Comment: BTW, this question is *NOT* a duplicate of the other question that is linked to the closed item here. (I voted to re-open. It may be a dupe of OTHER questions, but not of the one referenced in the close here.) In GoogleAnalytics V1, there was a class named GoogleAnalyticsTracker (this is LEGACY: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide). In V2 that class doesn't exist! V2 has "GoogleAnalytics" for the context and "Tracker" for tracking views and events and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to track Button clicks in google analytics but don't use trackPageView inside onClick() to track button events

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                tracker.trackPageView("/Categories");  //Error:  "The import com.google.android.apps cannot be resolved to a type"
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Categories.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Use this code for Button events tracking inside onClick() instead of above onClick() code

```
GaTracker.trackEvent("Your Buttons Category", "Your event name", "", 0L);
GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();
```

Declare

```
private Tracker GaTracker;
private GoogleAnalytics GaInstance;
```

Inside onCreate() method use

```
GaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
GaTracker  = GaInstance.getTracker("YOUR UA-Here");
GaTracker.sendView("/YourActivity"); // Include this line if you want to track page view
```

Answer (score 2):

GoogleAnalyticsTracker is used in libGoogleAnalyticsV1.jar but you are using libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar which is the latest version. To track a page view in libGoogleAnalyticsV2 use the following code
Declare

```
private Tracker GaTracker;
private GoogleAnalytics GaInstance;
```

Inside onCreate() method

```
GaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
GaTracker  = GaInstance.getTracker("YOUR UA-Here");
GaTracker.sendView("/YourActivity");
```